# Copy file from path in ListBox to a specific folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy a files that i selected from a `OpenFileDialog` and saved their path into a `ListBox`.
From the path into the `ListBox`, I want it to copy it into a specific folder.
So far, it is copying the entire source folder into the destination folder.

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.Stream myStream;
    OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    thisDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    thisDialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
    thisDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    thisDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    thisDialog.Multiselect = true;
    thisDialog.Title = "Please Select Attachments!";

    if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (String file in thisDialog.FileNames)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = thisDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(file);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    //after selecting the files into the openfile dialog proceed to action the below.

    foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}!", listBox1.ToString()));
        MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
        string sourceFolder = item.ToString();
        string destinationFolder = @"c:\\testing";

        //DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);
        DirectoryInfo directoryName = new DirectoryInfo( Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFolder));

        FileInfo[] files = directoryName.GetFiles();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string destinationPath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file.Name);
            File.Copy(file.FullName, destinationPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is mostly welcome. Thanks.

Comment: `It is pasting the entire source folder into the destination folder.` Can you explain, in other words, what you want it to do if **not** that?

Comment: if a selecting a file on the desktop from the openfiledialog. it is copying all items found on the desktop and paste it into the destination folder. i.e. c:\\testing

Comment: You are using the path of the selected file, then call `GetFiles()` to get the files list in that directory, then perform the copy of the Files in that path to the destination path. If you don't want that, why are you doing it? Is this some code you fished out of some other answer/site, but you don't really know what it does? You can just copy the file using the file name you find in each `ListBox` item and perform the copy using that reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the whole source directory as many times as many files you selected in the file picker, but you already have the full path of your files in your `ListBox`, you can simply iterate them over and copy them to the destination like:

```
string destinationFolder = @"c:\testing";
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    string sourcePath = item.ToString();
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath);
    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName);
    File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
}
```

Comment: Use [`listBox1.GetItemText(item);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext)